# Can anyone decipher this?

Tags: cipher

My friend just sent me this

**5627 4654554**

With a keyword of **'Digital'**

Which is apparently going to make this have some sense:

**At first, it's difficult to understand. But once you read down, you will see.**

Comment: I suggest adding hint now, if you can.

Comment: Looking at the numbers, when displayed on a digital clock, they become letters (when upside down). HSSHSGH LZGS. Given letter combination "HSSHS" I am thinking that it could correspond to a digraph substitution chart perhaps?

Comment: If you rot41 this you get: deaf cedcddc